# How to test a JAX-RS application using JUnit, Resteasy and Jetty

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, junit5, jetty-9

I am trying to write a JAX-RS based Restful application in a test-driven way. I don't want to use spring-boot, just the JavaEE spec and (mostly Wildfly-based) implementations thereof.

I wrote a very minimal implementation of a JAX-RS application and am trying to get an automated test working to the part where it fails in the way I expect it to (because the resource returns `null` on a `create`-call.

I want to create a setup where my test starts up a basic container, Jetty, that serves my application using Resteasy as the JAX-RS implementation. I then want to run a number of tests against the resources of my application, after which I want to tear down the server.

So far, so good, nothing special. However, I can't get it to work. I've tried a number of ways but it seems Resteasy is not automatically picking up my JAX-RS-annotated application and resource, even though it should be able to do so.

If I explicitly tell Resteasy what my application is, that seems to work at the least but then, of course, my resource doesn't get picked up.

My application class:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/service")
public class AssurancetourixRestApplication extends Application
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AssurancetourixRestApplication.class);

    public AssurancetourixRestApplication()
    {
        log.info("Application created");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class< ? >> getClasses()
    {
        log.info("getClasses called");
        return super.getClasses();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons()
    {
        log.info("getSingletons called");
        return super.getSingletons();
    }
}
```

My resource interface:

```java
@Path("insurance")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public interface InsuranceResource
{
    @GET
    public Response getAll();

    @POST
    public Response create(Insurance insurance);
}
```

Implementation of the resource:

```java
public class InsuranceResourceImpl implements InsuranceResource
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InsuranceResourceImpl.class);

    public InsuranceResourceImpl()
    {
        log.info("resource created");
    }

    @Override
    public Response create(Insurance insurance)
    {
        log.info("create called");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Response getAll()
    {
        log.info("getAll called");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>assurancetourix-rest</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>nl.crashdata.assurancetourix</groupId>
        <artifactId>assurancetourix</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>assurancetourix-rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Assurancetourix rest services</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Dependencies are managed in the parent pom. Resteasy is version 3.8.1.Final, jetty is version 9.4.19.v20190610

Test class

```java
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class InsuranceResourceTest
{
    private ResteasyClient resteasyClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();

    private Server server;

    @Test
    public void createInsurance()
    {
        Insurance insurance = new Insurance();
        insurance.setName("Test insurance");
        insurance.setPolicyNumber(123456789L);

        Response response = post(insurance);

        assertEquals(Status.CREATED, response.getStatusInfo());
    }

    private Response post(Insurance insurance)
    {
        return resteasyClient.target(server.getURI())
            .proxy(InsuranceResource.class)
            .path("/service")
            .create(insurance);
    }

    @BeforeAll
    protected void setUp()
    {
        this.server = new Server(0);

        ServletContextHandler context =
            new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setBaseResource(getWebAppRoot());

        ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder("default", HttpServlet30Dispatcher.class);
        context.addServlet(holder, "/*");
        server.setHandler(context);

        try
        {
            server.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @AfterAll
    protected void tearDown()
    {
        try
        {
            server.stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected Resource getWebAppRoot()
    {
        try
        {
            return Resource
                .newResource(new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath() + "/src/main/webapp"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
```

I expect to see an NPE in my log, along with the debug log statements I added, however all I see is:

> 19:06:49.157 [qtp707635461-24] DEBUG org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n - RESTEASY002305: Failed executing POST /service/insurance
>   javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://127.0.1.1:34977/service/insurance

Of note is I don't see the log statements from my classes.

With resteasy logging on TRACE I get nothing useful containing the name of my application or resource, but I do get:

> 19:06:49.150 [qtp707635461-24] DEBUG
>   org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n - RESTEASY002315: PathInfo:
>   /service/insurance 19:06:49.157 [qtp707635461-24] DEBUG
>   org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n - RESTEASY002305: Failed
>   executing POST /service/insurance javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException:
>   RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path:
>   http://127.0.1.1:34977/service/insurance  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:61)
>   ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.8.1.Final.jar:3.8.1.Final]     at
>   SNIP
>   19:06:49.176 [qtp707635461-24] DEBUG org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n -
>   MessageBodyWriter:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory$SortedKey 19:06:49.176
>   [qtp707635461-24] DEBUG org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n -
>   MessageBodyWriter: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar
>   19:06:49.176 [qtp707635461-24] DEBUG
>   org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n - MessageBodyWriter:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar 19:06:49.177
>   [qtp707635461-24] DEBUG org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n -
>   Interceptor Context:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext, 
>   Method : proceed 19:06:49.177 [qtp707635461-24] DEBUG
>   org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n - MessageBodyWriter:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory$SortedKey 19:06:49.178
>   [qtp707635461-24] DEBUG org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n -
>   MessageBodyWriter: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar

If I change the setUp method of my testclass to read:

```java
        this.server = new Server(0);

        ServletContextHandler context =
            new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");

        // // this should not be necessary
        ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder("default", HttpServletDispatcher.class);
        holder.setName("defaultservlet");
        holder.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application",
            "nl.crashdata.assurancetourix.rest.AssurancetourixRestApplication");
        context.addServlet(holder, "/*");
        server.setHandler(context);

        try
        {
            server.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Ie, I hardcode the full path to my jax-rs application, the application at least gets constructed but the resource doesn't seem to:

> 19:13:17.768 [qtp515520300-24] INFO 
>   nl.crashdata.assurancetourix.rest.AssurancetourixRestApplication -
>   Application created 19:13:17.770 [qtp515520300-24] INFO 
>   org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n - RESTEASY002225: Deploying
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class
>   nl.crashdata.assurancetourix.rest.AssurancetourixRestApplication
>   19:13:17.770 [qtp515520300-24] INFO 
>   nl.crashdata.assurancetourix.rest.AssurancetourixRestApplication -
>   getClasses called 19:13:19.759 [qtp515520300-24] INFO 
>   nl.crashdata.assurancetourix.rest.AssurancetourixRestApplication -
>   getSingletons called

And then nothing interesting until:

> 19:13:19.789 [qtp515520300-24] DEBUG
>   org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n - RESTEASY002305: Failed
>   executing POST /service/insurance javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException:
>   RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path:
>   http://127.0.1.1:39075/service/insurance

I'm hoping I'm doing something basic wrong. As I understand it from https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.8.1.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html, paragraph 3.3.1, I shouldn't have to hardcode application classnames or anything, it should just be picked up automagically.

> RESTEasy uses the ServletContainerInitializer integration interface in
>   Servlet 3.0 containers to initialize an application, automatically
>   scanning for resources and providers. To enable automatic scanning,
>   you must also include the resteasy-servlet-initializer artifact in
>   your WAR file as well

Hopefully I'm missing something really easy to fix and hopefully there's someone out there who can tell me what that is. :D

Answer (score 1):

In case that you don't need to use jetty there is the MockDispatcherFactory provided by resteasy, which makes the writing of Rest-Tests quite easy.

Have a look at:[Example of Resourcetest using restassured inherently using MockDispatcherFactory](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/blob/master/examples2/rest/minimal-resteasy3-war/src/test/java/org/oneandone/iocunit/rest/minimal_rest_war_test/RestResourceTest.java)
or [Test by using MockDispatcherFactory directly](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/blob/master/examples2/rest/ex7-simplerest/src/test/java/com/oneandone/iocunitejb/example7/ServiceTest.java)

Comment: Thank you very much.